# Custom module created is not working in server,works good in local environment

Tags: magento2, module, database, admin-panel, upgrade-script

We have created a custom module inside app/code and in upgrade schema script we have increased the module.xml version to add a new column to the existing table.Will it cause any issues?I am not able to trace the cause as it is working good in local.When fetched latest code from git in another local system also it is working good.

Comment: Have you somethig in the logs, check for uppercas

Comment: No its been developed in linux machine. So i dont think that case sensitivity is the issue.

Comment: Check the setup_module table and see if the recorded version of the module is the same or lower than the actual version of the module. If it’s the same, that means the module was already installed

Comment: Please check logs under var/log in root directory.Check also the updated version in setup_module with your packagename_module name search in table.